# Customize tab visibility of navigation bar in community portal based user profile

Tags: customer-community, user-profile, lightning-home-page, nav-tab

Is it possible to show/hide tabs of navigation bar of home page based on logged in user's profile in community portal.
We have used default CommunitiesLanding page for landing page after login.

[image: Community portal home page with navigation menu]
For example, Is it possible to hide tab of support for users who have customer profile and visible only to users who have staff profile?

Comment: What do you mean by [*tabs of navigation bar of home page*]? Can you post a screenshot with some more details to provide a bit of more information here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot disable particular menu options in the navigation menu on the standard template. Those are configured static in the community builder when you create the menu items and that there's no option to hide any specific it for a specific profile.

You have couple of options here:

- Create a page variation for the menu item that you don't want other users to see. Say you can create another page variation for Support menu and show a message like "You are not authorized to view this page" for Customer Profile users
- Create a custom theme and custom navigation menu, where you will have more control as who can view which menu options